# Blazor WebAsembly publish doesn't work properly

Tags: .net, blazor, publish

I have a Blazor WASM project. When I try to publish it - in result output directory contains only two entities: `web.config` file and `wwwroot` with static content. Here is my CLI command:

`dotnet publish -c Release -o ~/Desktop/output .`

and .csproj content (may be its important):

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <UseRazorSourceGenerator>false</UseRazorSourceGenerator>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

My dev env is macOS with .NET 6, but same behavior in Docker container based on Ubuntu.

Also, in publish logs I see message `Compressing Blazor WebAssembly publish artifacts. This may take a while...` which finish too fast (as I remember it's really should take some time)

Comment: Does the same happen when you try to publish a new project ?

Comment: Without the content of the publish logs it's a guessing game.